# Error with dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, openapi, dj-rest-auth

Everytime I run my server, I get this error on my terminal. I have tried researching about the cause but no luck with a response. This is the error below:

`CreateProfileView: could not resolve authenticator <class 'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication'>. There was no OpenApiAuthenticationExtension registered for that class. Try creating one by subclassing it. Ignoring for now.`

This is my rest_framework settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
}
```

Thanks.